# MS SQL PATINDEX and Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, patindex

Been banging my head at this for a few trying to come up with a clever way to regex (or if someone has a better idea) a size value from a very random string.  I've setup the below test to show what I'm working with, I'm trying to get the Final output in this statement to be like these in Green, and not these in Red by using the @pattern in the query to pull out the...

**Number x Number**

Hoping there's a regex or string guru out there that might have an idea for me :)

[image]

```
DECLARE @pattern AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @pattern = '%[0-9][0-9. x][0-9.x ][0-9. x]%'

BEGIN

    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 'Italy Terrazzo Sacra Nero 24x24 Honed' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Myorka Blue 2x8' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Chrysler Driftwood Hickory Sea 12mil Wear Layer Glue Down 6.3x48.4' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Myorka Blue 2x8' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Broadway Lvt Ash 9x72 Rigid Core Click- 6.0mm/28mil Wear Layer' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Minetta Concreto Pearl 2.5mm/28mil Wear Layer Glue Down 18x36' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Speak Leather Black 24 x 24' [Name]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Accent Montana White 12 x 36 Glossy' [Name]
    )


    SELECT 
         --FULL NAME--
          [Name]
         
         --HELPERS TO SEE WHAT I'M TESTING--
         ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%x%', [Name]) AS [START]
         ,SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%x%', [Name]), LEN([Name]))
         ,REVERSE([Name]) AS [REVERSE]
         ,LEN([Name]) AS [STRLenght]
         ,PATINDEX(@pattern, REVERSE([Name])) + 1
         ,LEN([Name]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^A-z]x%', REVERSE([Name])) + 1 AS [END]

         --FULL CALCULATION FOR FINAL OUTPUT--
         ,CASE WHEN [Name] LIKE '%[0-9] x [0-9]%'
               THEN SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%x%', [Name]), (LEN([Name]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%x%', REVERSE([Name])) + 1) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%x%', [Name]) + 1)
               WHEN [Name] LIKE '%[0-9]x[0-9]%'
               THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX(@pattern, [Name]), (LEN([Name]) - PATINDEX(@pattern, REVERSE([Name])) + 1) - PATINDEX(@pattern, [Name]) + 1), 'x', ' x ')
               ELSE NULL
            END AS [Final]
          FROM cte
END
```

---

### **--EDIT--**

I'm still trying to make sense of the query from Yitzhak has suggested.  There are still a few outliers I'm trying to attack by changing your

```
    ,c.query('
        for $x in /root/r[lower-case(text()[1])="x"]
        let $pos := count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        let $before := /root/r[$pos - 1]
           ,$twobefore := /root/r[$pos - 2]
           ,$after := /root/r[$pos + 1]

        return
            if (xs:decimal($before[1]) instance of xs:decimal and
                xs:decimal($after[1]) instance of xs:decimal and
                xs:string($twobefore[1]) instance of xs:string)
                    then data(($before, $x, $after))
            else if (xs:decimal($before[1]) instance of xs:decimal and
                     xs:decimal($after[1]) instance of xs:decimal and
                     xs:decimal($twobefore[1]) instance of xs:decimal)
                        then data(($twobefore, $before, $x, $after))
            else()
    ').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS result
```

This was in an attempt to attack this outlier case but doesn't seem to be getting the $twobefore which what I thought would get the 1 instead of missing it.

> Baroque Crackled 1 3/4 X 6 Chair Rail Blanco

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It's version 160

Comment: This link may help you make sense of Yitzhak's solution. https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xquery-20040723/ (the version is outdated, but  Microsoft states it uses XQuery Working draft 23 July 2004)

Comment: In your edit, "xs:decimal($before[1]) instance of xs:decimal and xs:decimal($after[1]) instance of xs:decimal" shoudl be an or.  "3/4" is not a decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization*.

It is leveraging SQL Server built-in XML and XQuery functionality.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing input string as XML.
- XQuery FLWOR expression traversing XML and filtering out any token
  that is not 'x' via the XPath predicate `[lower-case(text()[1])="x"]`.
- `/root/r[$pos - 1]` and `/root/r[$pos + 1]` XPath predicates get
  preceding and following tokens.
- `where` clause is checking for a decimal data type for at least one of
  the surrounding values.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Italy Terrazzo Sacra Nero 24x24 Honed'),
('Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone'),
('Myorka Blue 2x8'),
('Chrysler Driftwood Hickory Sea 12mil Wear Layer Glue Down 6.3x48.4'),
('Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone'),
('Broadway Lvt Ash 9x72 Rigid Core Click- 6.0mm/28mil Wear Layer'),
('Minetta Concreto Pearl 2.5mm/28mil Wear Layer Glue Down 18x36'),
('Speak Leather Black 24 x 24'),
('Accent Montana White 12 x 36 Glossy'),
('Baroque Crackled 1/2 X 6 Pencil Capri'),
('Banza Green Cielo 8" Hex'),
('Masia Torello Nero Brillo 3/4x12 Pencil'),
('Baroque Crackled 1 3/4 X 6 Chair Rail Blanco');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.*
    , c.query('
        for $x in /root/r[lower-case(text()[1])="x"]
        let $pos := count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
        let $before2 := /root/r[$pos - 2],
            $before := /root/r[$pos - 1],
            $after := /root/r[$pos + 1]
        where xs:decimal($before[1]) instance of xs:decimal 
            or xs:decimal($after[1]) instance of xs:decimal 
        return data((if (xs:decimal($before2[1]) instance of xs:decimal) then $before2 else ()
            , $before, $x, $after))
    ').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,'x', ' x '),SPACE(2),SPACE(1)), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
ORDER BY id;
```

**Output**

| id | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Italy Terrazzo Sacra Nero 24x24 Honed | 24 x 24 |
| 2 | Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone | 1 x 3 |
| 3 | Myorka Blue 2x8 | 2 x 8 |
| 4 | Chrysler Driftwood Hickory Sea 12mil Wear Layer Glue Down 6.3x48.4 | 6.3 x 48.4 |
| 5 | Nero Marquina 1x3 Herringbone | 1 x 3 |
| 6 | Broadway Lvt Ash 9x72 Rigid Core Click- 6.0mm/28mil Wear Layer | 9 x 72 |
| 7 | Minetta Concreto Pearl 2.5mm/28mil Wear Layer Glue Down 18x36 | 18 x 36 |
| 8 | Speak Leather Black 24 x 24 | 24 x 24 |
| 9 | Accent Montana White 12 x 36 Glossy | 12 x 36 |
| 10 | Baroque Crackled 1/2 X 6 Pencil Capri | 1/2 x 6 |
| 11 | Banza Green Cielo 8" Hex | NULL |
| 12 | Masia Torello Nero Brillo 3/4x12 Pencil | 3/4 x 12 |
| 13 | Baroque Crackled 1 3/4 X 6 Chair Rail Blanco | 1 3/4 x 6 |

Comment: This is interesting, it works, but has pointed out some other points in the data that return odd things like below.  I'm not familiar with this at all so trying to unpack what it's doing so I can modify it for additional odd balls like these.

Comment: Baroque Crackled 1/2 X 6 Pencil Capri, Banza Green Cielo 8" Hex, Masia Torello Nero Brillo 3/4x12 Pencil

Comment: It is always better to edit your original question, and provide a minimal reproducible example with DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. .

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the edge cases: (1) fractions with the forward slash, (2) upper cased "X".  Check it out.

Comment: Interesting approach.  Wouldn't this break for names with X in them?  Like "Exotic Henry's 5x4"

Comment: It does, the replace on words like "Hex" are causing issues.  I also check on the replace of "/" with "." and unfortunately that will also not work as it keeps the "." in the output.  I thought to replace the "." for a "/" later, but floats do also exist in the data which makes that not possible. I've never used XQuery before so this is a bit of a learning curve to understand this.

Comment: I made some adjustments to cover all provided test cases. Please give it a shot.

Comment: Made an edit in my original post, feel like I'm getting closer but not quite there.

Comment: Yitzhak may have better input, but you can add '$before2 := /root/r[$pos - 2]' to the let statement, then replace the current return with 'if (xs:decimal($before2[1]) instance of xs:decimal) then data(($before2, $before, $x, $after)) else(data(($before, $x, $after)))'

Comment: I adjusted the answer to handle the edge case. Check it out.